# Updating existing data in google datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am developing an application using Google App Engine and it's now still in the very early stage hence some modification to data models (both structural and content) are likely to happen. For example, I want to update the application user's username to add certain prefix to indicate which social network the user has logged in from (e.g. facebook, twitter, etc).
The problem is that I already have some data (although they are "beta" data) and I want to preserve them. So, deleting them and start from scratch is not an option.

My question, is there any way to do any kind of bulk update via GAE dashboard?
I would imagine, if it's an RDBMS, I want to do something like:
`UPDATE USER SET USERNAME = 'FB' + USERNAME`
What's general practice if you want to do something like this?
Must it be done by writing some code in your application to do this one-off task?

Even in production environment later, we may need to alter some data, delete unwanted records, add new configuration item, etc. Shouldn't there be any convenient way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no bulk update functionality available via API or admin console. You will have to write your own code to do this.

If you have a large dataset, then you will need to break down your update job into smaller tasks: the [map-reduce library](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInPython) can help you with breaking tasks into smaller parts and reliably execute them.

Comment: Thanks. It's inconvenient, if I compared to the traditional hosted RDBMS service. But that might be the price to pay for scalable data store. I'll have a look at MapReduce. It's an alien for me :)